# How to write Criteria Query Builder for select all from List?

Tags: jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need a query which will return only results which are having all values from the list.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads_tags 
WHERE tag_value("a", "b", "c");
```

I know that query is not good, but the point is that I want to filter ads but only ads which are having all tags from the list.

With my code, I am getting all ads that have at least one tag from the list. That is because I am using IN interface.

```
@Override
public List<AdsDTO> findAll(AdsSubGroup adssubgroup, Long userId, String status, String adsType,
                            String businessType, Long adsGroupId, String region, Integer fromPrice,
                            Integer toPrice, Boolean fixedPrice, Boolean freeDelivery, Boolean productWarranty,
                            Boolean urgentSales, Boolean hasImage, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize, List<String> tags) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Ads> query = builder.createQuery(Ads.class);
    Root<Ads> ads = query.from(Ads.class);
    // query.orderBy(builder.desc(ads.get("adsDate")));
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Join<Ads, JwtUser> adsUsersJoin = ads.join("users");
    Join<Ads, AdsSubGroup> adsAdsSubGroupJoin = ads.join("adssubgroup");
    Join<Ads, Tag> tagsJoin = ads.join("adsTags");
    In<List<String>> in = builder.in(tagsJoin.get("name"));


    if (tags != null && tags.size() > 0) {
        // in.value(tags);
        tags.forEach(tag - > in.value(tags));
        /*
         * for (String tag : tags) { in.value(tag);
         *
         * }
         */
        predicates.add(in);
    }

    query.select(ads);
    query.distinct(true);
    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    if (!(pageNumber == null && pageSize == null)) {
        TypedQuery<Ads> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        typedQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        List<Ads> adsList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
    } else {
        List<Ads> adsList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        return AdsConverter.convertToAdsDTO(adsList);
    }
}
```

What I need to write instead of In interface to get all ads which have ALL tags from the list, not at least one?

Answer (score 0):

You need a join for each element of type `Tag` in your list.
It's hard to fix your code because it's not a minimal example, however the following should help:

```
CriteriaQuery<Ads> query = builder.createQuery(Ads.class);
Root<Ads> ads = query.from(Ads.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
for (String tag : tags) {
    Join<Ads, Tag> tagsJoin = ads.join("adsTags");
    predicates.add(builder.equal(tagsJoin.get("name"), tag));
}
```